# Calling a web service async

Tags: android, web-services, design-patterns, rest, android-activity

I am building a android application and in my first activity I call to a web service in
AsyncTask (Virgil Dobjanschi design pattern).

But the line after the call i am moving to another activity like this:

```
ServiceHelper.CalcPoints(1,2);
Intent toSecond = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);    
startActivity(toSecond);
```

I don't wait for a callback from the server.

I want to know if I have risks in using that way ? and what them ?
If you recommend me not using that please give me other options.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

If you are using asyncTask then you must have known that it has three methods, onPreExecute(), doInBackgroung(), onPostExecute(). you should call your layout in onPreExecute method and u should also start a progress bar here. Then in doInBackgroundMethod u should call your web service. Last, onPostExecute method you should check for the web service response, if it is upto the requirement then stop progress bar and move to new activity, otherwise let the control remain on same screen with some Toast Message of wrong server response.

Hope you understand :)

Comment: how this answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

This is not safe.
When you start another activity, your current activity can be paused, killed etc.

Comment: pausing or killing activity not affect AsyncTask lifecycle